# Jquery registers randomly some on('click') events but not others

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

so I'm developing a blog site similar to tumblr using Laravel, Jquery & Ajax. To the problem, I have Jquery fire off an Ajax request using an `on('click')` event on the like button on dynamically created elements (however it does the same on the ones that are loaded through php initially). The problem is, some of the posts will allow you to like, but some that are identical(in structure) to the other posts will not register any clicks, I don't understand why it is not allowing these specific posts to not fire off click events when they're identical and others work. These posts are usually at the end of the ajax response (1,2,3 will work but 4,5 won't) however this isn't always the case, it seems kind of random.

**LikesController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post_id = $request->id;
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $existingLike = Like::where('post_id', $post_id)
                            ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                            ->first();

    if(!$existingLike)
    {
        $this->validate($request, 
            ['id' => ['required',
                Rule::unique('likes')->where(function ($query) use($post_id,$user_id) {
                    return $query->where('post_id', $post_id)
                ->where('user_id', $user_id);
            })],
        ]);

        $like = new Like;
        $like->user_id = $user_id;
        $like->post_id = $post_id;
        $like->save();
    }

    // return back();
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    
    $like = Like::where('post_id', $id)
                ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->first();

    $like->delete();

    // return back();
}
```

site.js(extract)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var page = 1;

    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            page++;
            loadMoreData(page);
        }
    });

    bindReblogButtonClick();
    bindDeleteButtonClick();
    bindLikeButtonClick();
    bindOpenCloseEditPost();
    bindUpdatePostText();
    bindSubmitEditPostForm();
    bindSubmitCreatePostForm();
    bindOpenCloseCreatePost();
});

function loadMoreData(page) {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'posts/?page=' + page,
            type: "get",
            // beforeSend: function () {
            //     $('.ajax-load').show();
            // }
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.html == "") {
                    console.log("No more records found");
                    return;
                }
                // $('.ajax-load').hide();
                $("#posts").append(response.html);
                bindReblogButtonClick();
                bindDeleteButtonClick();
                bindLikeButtonClick();
                bindOpenCloseEditPost();
            },
            error: function (error){

            }
        });
}

function bindLikeButtonClick(){
    $('.like-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var count = $(this).data('count');

        //do if else statement instead using hasclass on the like button

        if ($(this).hasClass('like-button-delete')) {
            $(this).removeClass('like-button-delete');

            count = count - 1;
            $(this).data('count', count);
            $(this).parent().find('.likeCount').text(count);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'like/' + id,
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    _method: 'DELETE'
                },
                success: function (response) {
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    bulmaToast.toast({
                        message: error,
                        position: "bottom-right",
                        type: "is-danger",
                        dismissible: true
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('like-button-delete');

            count = count + 1;
            $(this).data('count', count);
            $(this).parent().find('.likeCount').text(count);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/like?id=' + id,
                data: { id: id },
                success: function (response) {
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

If you need anymore information, let me know, it also doesn't work for the edit post buttons on these posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the click handler was sending off 2 click listeners used `$('.like-button').off().on('click', function (e)` to take off the handler and add it again and it fixed my issue.

Comment: Well, that is one way of doing it. A more elegant approach would have been to do the whole event binding as "delegated event listening" on a parent container (or the document) *once* (after the document has loaded) with `.on(eventType,actualElementSelector", function)`.